# FormatDateTime - Integer arithmetic overflow C++

Tags: c++, datetime, integer-overflow

I'm using a C++ builder function which allows me to format a time received from my microcontroller as below:

```
void DisplayTime(unsigned long SecondsSince1900, unsigned short FractionOfSecond, AnsiString* DecodedString)
{
    TDateTime WindowsDate;
    double FloatingDate;
    FloatingDate = SecondsSince1900 + (FractionOfSecond / 65536.0);

    if ( (SecondsSince1900 & 0x80000000) == 0 )
    {// Seconds since wraps around during year 2036.
     // When the top bit is clear we assume that the date is after 2036         rather than before 1968.
        FloatingDate += 0x100000000;//this line is the cause of the warning
    }

    FloatingDate /= SECONDS_IN_DAY ;
    WindowsDate = FloatingDate ;
    *DecodedString = FormatDateTime(" yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss ", WindowsDate);
}
```

Using this code I get the following warning:

> Integer arithmetic overflow

Is there any solution to avoid this issue?

Comment: Your comments talk about the 2038 problem, but that happens when dealing with the Unix epoch of 0 being 1970. That doesn't match your variable names. Are you sure you have all your math right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although some compilers will interpret the constant `0x100000000` as a 64-bit integer, it seems that yours does not - which makes it too big to fit into a 32-bit integer (hence the warning).

A simple way around this is to replace the integer constant with a `double` value:

```cpp
FloatingDate += 4294967296.0;
```

Alternatively (if your compiler supports it) you can add the `uLL` suffix to the integer constant:

```cpp
FloatingDate += 0x100000000uLL;
```

But this may cause a different warning (conversion from `unsigned long long` to `double` can cause loss of precision).

Comment: Please do not advise to use double constants to initialize long values! What about `long val = 8070450532247928831.0;`? `val` will recieve the value 8070450532247928832 that is 1 more than expected! double mantissa is only 48 bits long while a long can have up to 63 (or 64 if unsigned) significant bits, which cause the inaccuracy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer you mean I repalce `0x100000000 by 4294967296.0`?

Comment: @SergeBallesta There is no long value being initialized - `FloatingDate` is a `double` and the code adds a `double` constant to it.

Comment: @geek - Yes, that's it.

Comment: @Serge Again, depends on whether `long` is 32- or 64-bit on OP's system: 'long long` is far more likely to be 64-bit.

Comment: @AdrianMole: you are aware of that, but your answer could be misleading for a beginner... BTW as the answer was correct in that context, I had not downvoted...